# <Redirect /> is not redirecting to the desired component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have set up the routes for child components in the following parent component as sho

```
const AdminPage = props => (
    <div>
     //some other code
     <Switch>
         //some other routes
         <Route
            exact
            path = path={props.match.url + "/flights/:flightNumber/passengers"}
            component={PassengersPage}
         />
         <Route exact path="/add-passenger" component={PassengerAddPage} />
     </Switch>
   </div>
);

export default AdminPage;
```

The following is the PassengersPage child component

```
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

class PassengersPage extends React.Component {
   state = {
     redirectToAddPassengerPage: false
   };
    render() {
       return (
         <>
           {this.state.redirectToAddCoursePage && <Redirect to="add-passenger" />}
           //some presentational JSX

           <button
              style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}
              className="btn btn-primary add-course"
              onClick={() => {
              this.setState({ redirectToAddPassengersPage: true });
              }}
            >
              Add Passenger
           </button>
         </>
        );
    }
 }
```

But nothing happens on button click. There is no error logs in console as well.
Please help.

Comment: Try with `<Redirect to="/add-passenger" />`

Comment: does't work. Nothing happens

Comment: I think you have a typo in state object. You have `redirectToAddPassengerPage` in your state, while you are setting `redirectToAddPassengersPage` in the click event of button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two states, one of which controls the Redirect but it's not set in the button click:

```
class PassengersPage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    redirectToAddPassengerPage: false
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        // This next line needs to be changed to 'redirectToAddPassengersPage'
        {this.state.redirectToAddPassengersPage && <Redirect to="add-passenger" />}

        <button
          style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}
          className="btn btn-primary add-course"
          onClick={() => {
          this.setState({ redirectToAddPassengersPage: true });
          }}
        >
          Add Passenger
        </button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using push method of history. Also Try extracting the click to setting the state, and on the call back use push to redirect to your necessary path.

```
clickHandler = () => {
        this.setState({ redirectToAddPassengersPage: true },
                          () => {
                             this.props.history.push("/add-passenger");
        })
}
```

Or going with your approach try passing **push={true}** . Something like

```
<Redirect to="/add-passenger" push={true}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are updating `redirectToAddPassengersPage` on state but checking condition on `redirectToAddPassengersPage`.

Try Updating your code like below

```
{this.state.redirectToAddPassengerPage && <Redirect to="/add-passenger" />}
```